# How to make a vector layer with Hebrew caption in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, vector, utf-8, hebrew

I am working in Qgis and need to make layers with Hebrew caption.
When I make a new layer and write a word in Hebrew, in this case on a point vector layer that I made, it looks just fine. [image]
However, when I save the layer the Hebrew word is replaced with question marks in the Attribute table and in the caption on the map. [image]
  I tried to change the Unicode control character into right-to-left, but it did not solve the problem. [image]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing you created a shapefile layer. You have to choose a good "file encoding" already at creation time, in the same dialog.

Using QGIS 2.18, I created a new layer and chose the UTF-8 encoding (ISO 8859-8 or Windows-1255 should be fine too). Then I added a text field to it and copy/pasted some Hebrew into them from the internet. Editing the layer properties to show the labels worked as expected and everything was drawn. Saved and restarted QGIS and everything still worked.

So like I said, I suspect you didn't choose a good encoding when creating the layer. Shapefiles don't support unicode by default.