# Using file path in QgsVectorLayer?

Tags: qgis, python, qgsvectorlayer

After hours of tries and errors I can't get this right in QGIS 2.99.

I want to add a layer with the delimitedtext function in QgsVectorLayer but if I 
add this code to my plugin, or if I'm running it in the python-console:

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

fullname = "C:/åäö/myfile.txt"
filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]
uri = 'file:///%s?crs=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&decimal=%s' % (fullname, 'EPSG:3006', ',', 'East', 'North', '.')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, filename, 'delimitedtext')
if layer:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
    print("Done")
else:
    print("Error")
```

I'm getting an error that the file can't be opened, if I change the file path to "C:/abc/myfile.txt" everything's working fine. In QGis 2.18 i solved it with adding a .encode('utf-8') to the path, but that's not working anymore.

If I'm saving that code in a file and makeing my plugin run that file with this code, it's working.
But in this way I can't use it because the file is coming from a user input through the filedialog window.

```
with open(u'C:/åäö/TESTdelimitedText.py') as f:
    exec(f.read())
return
```

or if I run it in the editor in python-console in Qgis.

In the ogr provider its working without any problems.

How do I make QgsVectorLayer delimitedtext accept a file path with special characters?

Comment: This sounds similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242688/how-to-make-a-vector-layer-with-hebrew-caption-in-qgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [issue #11274](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11274), you have to take care of non-ASCII characters yourself when using the delimited text provider. This unlike other providers that deals with it themself.

The simplest way is to import quote from urllib.parse 
 
`from urllib.parse import quote` 
and use it to encode your filepath 
`file_name = quote(path_to_file)`

example:

```
file_names = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self.iface.mainWindow(), 
                                                               "Select  files", 
                                                               "C:/", 
                                                               "Files (*.txt *.shp)")
if file_names:
    for path_to_file in file_names:
        if path_to_file.endswith('.txt'):
            layer_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path_to_file))[0]
            file_name = quote(path_to_file)
            uri = 'file:///%s?crs=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&decimal=%s&useHeader=%s' % 
            (file_name, 'EPSG:3006', ',', 'East', 'North', '.', 'yes')
            layer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri, layer_name, 'delimitedtext')
```

quote() works on both QGIS 2.18 and 3.0
But remember not to use it with the 'ogr' provider if you importing shapefiles or similar.