# Converting Hebrew Excel file into Shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, csv

I have an Excel that was written in Hebrew that I need to convert into Shapefile file. I am working with Windoes 7 and with  QGIS 2.18.17. 
When I was converting the Excel into CSV I used "CSV (Comma delimited" format.
I also took care to be sure that the numbers and the words in the Excel columns are in the correct encoding.

[image]

The result was an error with the layout of the Hebrew words.
[image]

I head tried [other kinds of encoding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242688/how-to-make-a-vector-layer-with-hebrew-caption-in-qgis) for the Excel conversion and for the Delimited text file as well Including, but it did not help.

Comment: If you open the csv file with a text editor (like Notepap++), can you see the hebrew characters? I think the problem is not with QGis, but with Excel export to csv. Can you try to save as Unicode text, instead of csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Leyan mentioned, the problem is almost definitely in the export from Excel to CSV. Here's one workaround that worked for me:

1) Open your Excel file (.xlsx/xls)
2) Click Save As and select 'Unicode Text (*.txt)'. Save your file somewhere.
3) Open this .txt file in QGIS, and then just change the File Format to custom delimiters -> Tab:

[image]

Btw, if you have Excel 2013, there is another format that will work: 'CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)', but it does not seem to appear in the context menu screenshot you attached.